# VB Error creating the form

Tags: vb.net

guys! I'm creating a vending machine app for my final project, but ran into a minor issue. When I try to run it i get the following error, An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm assuming it has something to do with my label.text that i have converted into a double because that's when the problem arose. If someone could provide me with a work around it would be much appreciated!

```
Public Class VendingMachine
Dim balance As Double = CDbl(balanceLabel.Text)
'Dim intbalance As String = balanceLabel.Text
'Dim balance As Double = Convert.ToDouble(intbalance)


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles depositButton.Click
    If nickleButton.Checked = True Then
        balance = +0.05
        balanceLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", balance)
    End If

    If dimeButton.Checked = True Then
        balance = +0.1
        balanceLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", balance)
    End If

    If quarterButton.Checked = True Then
        balance = +0.25
        balanceLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", balance)
    End If

    If dollarButton.Checked = True Then
        balance = +1.0
        balanceLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", balance)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles refundButton.Click
    balance = 0.0
    balanceLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", balance)
    MsgBox("Money Refunded")
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles starburstPicture.Click
    If balance >= 1.25 Then
        balance = balance - 1.25
    Else
        MsgBox("You do not have enough money to purchace that item.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub jollyrancherPicture_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles jollyrancherPicture.Click
    If balance >= 1.0 Then
        balance = balance - 1.0
    Else
        MsgBox("You do not have enough money to purchace that item.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub gummyPicture_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles gummyPicture.Click
    If balance >= 0.75 Then
        balance = balance - 0.75
    Else
        MsgBox("You do not have enough money to purchace that item.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub peppermintPicture_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles peppermintPicture.Click
    If balance >= 0.75 Then
        balance = balance - 0.75
    Else
        MsgBox("You do not have enough money to purchace that item.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub VendingMachine_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: "balanceLabel" is Nothing, you'll need a constructor (Sub New) and not use the identifier until *after* InitializeComponent().

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to get values from controls before it's loaded - declaring a variable based on a controls property in the class scope. Just declare the variable and figure out where and when it needs to be set - otherwise it's empty anyway - right?

Edit: What `Hans Passant` said.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense haha. Thank you both!!

Comment: "What Hans Passant said" is not an answer.

Comment: There is an error creating the form, both Hans and myself are correct in this matter - he just needed to explain it better. Thanks for your unhelpful comment Ken.